# PhoneGap - Keyboard makes the screen go black and flickery for some time on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, mobile-safari

I am developing mobile apps using HTML5 & CSS3 using PhoneGap. My problem is that whenever I touch a textbox on my webpage running on the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android v3.1), it shows the keyboard but the page goes black for a fraction of second. At times, it flickers for a while showing black background and then restores itself.

I even tried with a simple page with a single `input type="text"` and it even happens with the same.

Anybody faced a similar issue and have had a fix for it?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

As I said above, the black flickering even happens with the app containing a simple page with a single text box. Following is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Flickering Problem </title>
        <style>
            html, body{
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                overflow: hidden;
                -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" width="200px" height="100px" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I tested this on my Android tablet, and the flickering was as with a full fledged web page.
I tried adding certain CSS attributes suggested here on SO for similar problem which claimed to solve, but did actually help.

It is worth noting that the black flickering is happening whenever we try to enter any text in the textbox, and I am currently not doing any animation(s) / transitions using CSS3.

Comment: which plattform is this running on, does this only happen on android?

Comment: Is the behavior consistent with multiple tablets or only one?

Comment: I am testing it on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1.. (Android V3.1)

Comment: example code would be nice to see, could you edit your question or maybe use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @PhillPafford: I added the sample code, may be you'd like to give it a try!

Comment: Are there any similar fixes for Java Android SDK ? I am getting similar issues.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to enable hardware-acceleration in the android manifest.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ... />
```

This enables double-buffering through the GPU and resolves the problem.
Note that this option is only available in Android 3.0+.

Here's the background for all you techies: :)
We have recently been testing a functional jQuery Mobile HTML5 app wrapped with PhoneGap Android 2.x phones to the Galaxy tab 10.1.
We have seen something very similar, with the exception that we have defined a splash screen for our app.
What we see is that when an input field is given focus, the screen flashes up the splash screen momentarily. Very annoying! To verify if this is the same problem, define a splash screen for your PhoneGap app and see if the screen flahes your image instead of a black background.
Knowing something about what's going on with PhoneGap and the Android WebView, this is my best estimation of what is happening:
PhoneGap loads the main App activity with a black background and displays the splash screen (if defined) in that initial window.
PhoneGap then starts the WebView and opens it on top of the main Window.
When a field is selected, the Android invalidates the component wach time it updates it based on a focus event or keypress, or whatever, and Android redraws everything. So it redraws the main window behind the WebView and then redraws the WebView with the HTML page content on top of it. Since the device is not properly double-buffered, you see all of this redrawing in all its ugly glory right in front of your eyes.

We have seen serious glitches with Android web forms on some Android 2.x phones we have tested, and this looks like yet another glitch, but this time on the Galaxy Tab running Honeycomb (3.0).

We have attempted to use CSS **-webkit-backface-visibility** to resolve issues on some phones when experiencing flicker in the past - but *this has caused serious rendering issues in HTML forms*. Be warned! In theory this should be a viable fix to introduce some double-buffering into the mix, but in our experience it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: hey, you are right about the SplashScreen. Even I have seen this problem with jQuery Mobile in my full-fledged application. It also appears between page transitions..

Answer (score 4):

This is either a problem with the Android OS or Phonegap.

*If it's a problem with Android*, this can only be fixed with a software update to the OS. You can test this out by going to a regular website with a text box and tapping on it to enter text. If it flickers, it's probably the OS.

*If it's a problem with Phonegap*, it might be fixed by doing a specific search for that. Looking at the top results in google, I've found this:

http://www.senchatouchbits.com/6/fixing-flickering-of-animations-in-phonegap.html

This suggests you put `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` into your code. While I see you put it into the `html, body` tag, try putting it into the `*` tag, ex:

```
*{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Note: The link puts the style onto a `.x-panel` tag, I'm not sure if that's specific to their code or to Android.**

Here's another link that you should look into for a fix: http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=301

Comment: Hi, `*{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}` didn't solve the problem. Personally, I don't think this is a problem with Android OS, because similar problems have found to occur on iOS platform too. I believe there would be some CSS / HTML hack that may solve the problem...

Comment: Do a google specific google search for the problem. I can't replicate it because I don't have your app or the Android OS.

Comment: @mahi: I’ve just popped [your example code up on my website](http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/8046036/) and tested it with an iPad 1 running iOS 5.0.1. When I tap on the text field, the screen does not go black, or flicker at all. I haven’t got a Galaxy Tab, so I can’t test there. Could you check my test page on your Galaxy Tab, and see if the issue occurs for you?

Comment: @mahi: ah, of course the test page on my site doesn’t involve PhoneGap. Hm.

Comment: @mahi: but if you see the same problem on the Galaxy Tab using my test page, then that at least eliminates PhoneGap. (And if you don’t, I’d guess it’s PhoneGap’s issue.)

Comment: I'll test the page on my tablet and update you with the results.

Comment: You know what, remove the `webkit-overflow-scrolling` tag and see if it changes anything. That CSS tag is so buggy, it messes everything up on my pages.

Answer (score 1):

I added a demo page:

http://jsbin.com/upixel/

From your code, the `input` is big (width and height need to be set by css) - if that is the case, the black color may come from the **default tap color** and the flickering may come from **blocking** (phonegap or script's fault)

see will this solve your flickering:

```
      * {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
      }
```

[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/upixel/3/)

Hope it can help

Comment: No, using the code inside the CSS of my PhoneGap app still shows the same behaviour...

Comment: Did you try to put the demo page code into a **blank** phonegap project? Since the environment is different, we need to eliminate other scripting factors in order to find the causes.

Comment: Yes, I copied the page into a `new` phonegap project, which does not contain any other `CSS` or `other` code.

Comment: Seems this is caused by the phonegap js/css problem (they may do something on :focus...and this is problematic)...report it to phonegap to see they can provide any help.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll report this on PhoneGap users group. Hope some PhoneGap employee / expert takes a look at this issue, if its one from their end :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem and at the beginning I thought it had to do with the manifest part of the app.

After hours of troublesolving this is what worked for me. (Still haven't had the problem after an hour of testing on the phone. A samsung galaxy s2, version 4.0.3. And for the app I'm using verison 2.1).

html{background:url(img/brownBG.PNG) repeat 0 0;}

I just put a background on the html and now it works fine. If you try this solution, please comment if it works for you or not.

EDIT: I also have this css rule which is important for it to work
*{-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}

Comment: I believe the `img/brownBG.PNG` is your custom image... Is is something like a generic background image which can work on most of the devices? If yes, can you post the link to the image for me to download so that I can try it out? Thanks.

Comment: It's just an image I made i photoshop, if my solution works in the way I think it does, yoy could use any background:; a background-image or a background-color.

A link to the bg I use.
https://github.com/antpant89/Sharing/blob/master/brownBG.PNG

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a solution to this, I found the support ticket for this bug: 
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15365

> As of today, the best workaround consists in using the adjustPan Android option plus the above subclass of ScrollableView? (if you can afford creating an APK dedicated for Android >= 3, you can also add the hardwareAccelerated option). This solves all troubles except the field duplication on Android 4. Of course, if the ScrollableView? is not really mandatory in the view containing text fields, replacing it by a View is even better.

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction to the solutions mentioned already (i.e. -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; and android:hardwareAccelerated="true"), I have also tried either one of the following:

(Applicable only on Android version >= 3)

1. AndroidManifest.xml

   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
2. MyActivity.java

   ```
   this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

       public void run() {

           getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

       }

   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 like yours.While I upgraded android version from 3.1 to 4.0.3(using Cyanogenmod 9.0 nightly build 20120302) and without any code change, the problem was solved on my device.

So I guess that it's an issue of webview component on Galaxy Tab android version.

Answer (score 0):

I have a proven solution for this problem, I was also facing same problem but I solved it myself.
First create a  field inside body and make it hidden or you can make it hide behind a div using z-index so that it won't be visible.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('example').value='';
});
 </script>
   <body>
   <div style='z-index:50;position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;'>
   Your page matter here</div>
    <select id='example' style='z-index:10'>
    <option value=''>a</option>
    </select></pre>
   </body>
```

The moto is that we have to set this select field when the page load, and doing this will stop the flickering for sure...try it guys.....it worked for me

Answer (score -2):

I can't say this will fix your problem, but it is worth a shot. Check your AndroidManifest.xml file for `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in the `activity` tag (under application).

Comment: Yes, I am having it in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Oh well, it was a shot in the dark. Hope you get it figured out.